# Given $\sum =\{a,b\}$ , give some example of strings in, and not in these sets where: $\{w\mid: ww=www\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

For a string not in $\{w\mid: ww=www\}$ one can simply choose $w=a$

But, the only way I can see a string being in $\{w\mid: ww=www\}$ is if $w=\lambda$ (the empty string), but $\lambda$ is not part of the alphabet. Is this wrong?

Comment: My guess: probably the problem means that if $w = a*$, then $ww = a*a*$ and $www = a*a*a*$?

Comment: So that would mean that $w=a^*$ is not in the set  since the strings generated by $ww=www$ would start with different lengths of $a$. Right?

Comment: no, if regular expressions are allowed, $a*a*$ and $a*a*a*$ denote the exact same set of strings: zero or any arbitrary numbers of $a$s.

Answer (score 2):

Although $\lambda$ is not in the alphabet, it is still a string, and in fact it is the only string in that language. Since $ww\lambda$=$www$, it follows that $w=\lambda$.